# Unity 3d to play 2 animations at once

Tags: unity-game-engine, animator, unity3d-mecanim

I got the Skeleton model from Unity Asset Store. The model has several animations, including a walking animation. I additionally made an animation of rotation. I need to play the walking animation, then play the animation of the turn, but continued to play animation walk. I'm using Animator (Mecanim). If you do the transition, then the animation ends walk. The only way I could think of is to use different layers. But from what I understand they are designed for other purposes. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: you can just use different layers as you said. works perfectly in my games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different layers and masks to blend multiple animations.
You can have a look at here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SAnr8-Xfgg 
Unity tutorial on Avatar Mask:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/avatar-masks

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Apparently this is really the only correct way to do it.